# Random pick some elements from array in Typst?

Tags: typst

How to select some elements from array randomly?

```
 let array = ("one", "two", "three", "1", "2", "3", "4")  
 array.pick(10)
```

Comment: Random number generation is apparently still an open feature request (s. https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/984). So, there is no first-hand implementation yet.

Comment: @lema Thanks you. I will keep an eye on this issue.

Comment: We are unlikely to ship a random number generator because drawing a different number at each compilation would break incremental compilation. You can instead write a simple PRNG and seed it with the current date (or any other value) to make some reasonably distributed picks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`suiji`](https://typst.app/universe/package/suiji/) package provides a pseudo-random number generator. With it, you can write a `pick` function that returns random elements from the array:

```
#import "@preview/suiji:0.1.0"

// This will pick the same but random items every time
#let pick(num, arr) = {
  // Generate the RNG with a random seed.
  // This could also use `datetime.today().day()` or something
  // similar to return a different number every day.
  // If consecutive invocations need to yield different values,
  // you can alternatively pass the seed as an argument.
  let rng = suiji.gen-rng(3585789)
  suiji.integers(rng, high: arr.len(), size: num)
    .at(1)
    .map(idx => arr.at(idx))
}

#let array = ("one", "two", "three", "1", "2", "3", "4") 
#pick(10, array)
```

Note that this function will do the following:

- Return randomly distributed items from an array
- Return the same picks every time for a given length

This is because there is no true source of randomness in Typst so that incremental recompilation works. You can factor out the seed argument and pass a different seed every time if you need to get different picks at each call site.